# EasyMock, return any object, or skip that function call?

Tags: java, testing, easymock

Using EasyMock, how do I specify returning "anyObject"?  I get an exception if I try to use "`.addReturns(anyObject())`".

Or is there a way to just relax EasyMock's requirements and just say, its ok if you call this additional method?

Basically my function is calling `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` and i really don't care that its calling that or what it returns.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is

```
createNiceMock()
```

http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/2.4/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#createNiceMock%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 0):

Amir's answer about "nice mocks" is the right way to do this with EasyMock, but perhaps you'd be better off with a fully stubbed-out version of HttpServletRequest such as Spring's [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html), which rather than a dynamic mock just provides an implementation of the interface which provides straight-forward implementations of all the methods.

Having to specify each of the methods you want to call on the servlet request/response sounds like it would be tiresome and tedious - I think it's rational to expect that servlet-layer code is pretty tightly coupled to these request/response objects.